# Signed Stored Procedures and Application Role Security conflict

Tags: sql-server

In order to remove Trustworthy on our database, per an audit finding, we are switching to signed stored procedures. In particular we are wanting a stored proc to be able to select against `sys.dm_exec_connections`. So we created a user/cert/signed proc that seems to work perfectly for non-privileged users except when the users are running under `application role` security and then it is like the stored proc is not signed at all. The trace indicates that the stored proc is erroring when attempting to select against `sys.dm_exec_connections` Are digitally signed procs and application role security incompatible?  The error we are getting is

> "The module being executed is not trusted. Either the owner of the database of the module needs to be granted authenticate permission, or the module needs to be digitally signed."

For testing I have even granted 'sa' to the signing user account with no luck.

```
PRINT 'Creating Cert';
EXEC (N'
CREATE CERTIFICATE ' + @certName + '
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''' + @password + ''' 
    WITH SUBJECT = '' Certificate used to do grants '',   
    EXPIRY_DATE = ''12/31/2099'' 
    ');  

PRINT 'Getting Cert Binary';
DECLARE @Cert NVARCHAR(4000) =
     CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000),
             CERTENCODED(CERT_ID(@certName)),
             1);

PRINT 'Copying cert to master';
EXEC (N'
USE [master];
CREATE CERTIFICATE ' + @certName + '
FROM BINARY = ' + @Cert
);

PRINT 'Creating login, in master, with cert';
EXEC (N'
USE [master];
CREATE LOGIN ' + @UserName + '
FROM CERTIFICATE ' + @certName + ';
');

IF @installIntoMSDB = 'Y'
BEGIN
    print 'Creating cert in msdb';
    EXEC (N'
    USE [msdb];
    CREATE CERTIFICATE ' + @certName + '
    FROM BINARY = ' + @Cert
    );

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM msdb.sys.server_principals WHERE name = 
@UserName)
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Creating login, in msdb, with cert';
            EXEC (N'
                USE [msdb];
                CREATE LOGIN ' + @UserName + '
                FROM CERTIFICATE ' + @certName + ';
                ');
        END;
END;
....
SET @tsql = 'ADD SIGNATURE TO ' + @objectName + ' BY CERTIFICATE ' + 
@certName + ' WITH PASSWORD = ''' + @password + ''';';
```

Comment: That SQL looks very open to Injection. If you do *need* to use dynamic SQL you should be ensuring your properly quote your values (using `QUOTENAME`_, and parametrising your values where you can (using `sp_executesql`). [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: Yes injection can be an issue but users are not running this code and I control what the inputs are.

Comment: That doesn't mean you should use injection open SQL.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on the problem that signed certs and app role security appear to conflict somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Solved: We signed the procs which at first appeared to work however when app role security is enabled this breaks.  We ended doing the following additional steps:

1. 'Create User MySpecialUser WITHOUT LOGIN'
2. Grant needed permissions to MySpecialUser....
3. Added the following to procs that needed to run '....WITH EXECUTE AS 'MySpecialUser ....'
4. added '....GRANT AUTHENTICATE SERVER TO SpecialViewStateCredAccount'.
5. Sign procs like normal.....